# What happens when parent class object is assigned child class object?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, parent-child

This following code gives the output as :

```
Output:
  Animal
  Dog
  Animal
```

I'm confused why "a.type" outputs as "Animal" even after the assignment "a=b". Why is it so?

Another observation was when I don't declare variable - "String type" inside Dog class. Then I get the output as :

```
    Output:
      Dog
      Dog
      Dog
```

My code:

```
    //Parent class
    class Animal {
        String type;
        public Animal(){
           this.type= "Animal";
       }

    }

    //Child class
    class Dog extends Animal {

       String type;
       public Dog(){
           this.type ="Dog";
       }

    }

    //Main Class To Test
    class TestDog{


          Animal a = new Animal();   
          Dog b = new Dog();        
          Animal c = new Dog();     

          a = b;
          System.out.println(a.type);
          System.out.println(b.type);
          System.out.println(c.type);


    }
```

Comment: `"What happens when parent class object is assigned child class object?"` -- *Ahem*, please understand that you're assigning a child class object to a parent type ***variable***. This may seem picky, but it's an important distinction and gets to the core of how Java implements OOPs and uses *reference* variables. Also the parent type might not even be a class, but could be an interface (a "pure" type).

Comment: You're adding a type field to both the parent and the child class. Don't. Add it to the Parent only. Make it protected or give it getters and setters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First a didactic point. You state in your tile:

> What happens when parent class object is assigned child class object?

Please understand that you're assigning a child class object to a parent type variable. This may seem picky, but it's an important distinction and gets to the core of how Java implements OOPs and uses reference variables. Also the parent type might not even be a class, but could be an interface (a "pure" type).

As for your confusion, you're adding a type field to both the parent and the child class. Don't, since fields aren't overridden. Add it to the Parent only. Make it protected or give it getters and setters.

For example:

```
class Animal {
    private String type;

    public Animal() {
        this.type = "Animal";
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

}
```

```
// Child class
class Dog extends Animal {

    String type;

    public Dog() {
        setType("Dog");
    }

}
```

```
// Main Class To Test
class TestDog {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Animal a = new Animal();
        Dog b = new Dog();
        Animal c = new Dog();

        a = b;
        System.out.println(a.getType());
        System.out.println(b.getType());
        System.out.println(c.getType());
    }

}
```